# Как разбить один contenteditable на два

Tags: javascript, html

Как разбить по курсору один contenteditable на два при помощи javascript, с сохранением форматирования. А при нажатии backspace слить вместе.
Идея заключается в следующем. После того как пользователь нажимает на кнопку, contenteditable делиться на на два, а между ними вставляется canvas для рисования.

Comment: Зачем? о_О Возможно, поможет оборачивания range в элемент.

Comment: @ermak0ff, что же не так с вопросом?

Comment: А что плохого, если canvas будет внутри contenteditable?

Comment: Данную проблему я рассматриваю в вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464669/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-canvas-%D0%B2-contenteditable и если у вас есть хорошие идеи как это сделать, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) надо юзать. Но тут будет много проблем.
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset вернет начальную позицию курсора на элементе window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer, причем startContainer не обязательно это div[contenteditable="true"], может быть любым элементов внутри самого contenteditable