# Как вставить canvas в contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, html5

Пытаюсь вставить canvas в contenteditable при помощи следующей функции

```
    $('div[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function(e) {
            var insert = 
                  '<div class="row">'+
                  '<div class="col-md-12">'+
                  '<canvas class="sig-canvas" width="620" height="160"></canvas></div></div>';
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                   document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, insert);
                   return false;
            }
    });
```

Но проблема в том что canvas вставляется и не работает.
Как встроить canvas в contenteditable?

Ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined.
Как добавить контекст после встраивания canvas?
Использую sketch.js. http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/
Подключаю так:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
            $('.sig-canvas').sketch();
       });
    </script>
```

Это все перед закрывающим тегом body

Comment: Для того чтобы рисовать в тексте.

Comment: А что конкретно не работает? Что пишет консоль? В какой момент вы и как пользуетесь канвасом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Всем спасибо за участие. И все таки canvas внутри contenteditable работает.

```
    $('div[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<canvas class="sig-canvas" width="620" height="160"></canvas>');
                  $(function() {
                        $('.sig-canvas').sketch();
                  });
                  return false;
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Из [MDN](http://web-standards.ru/articles/contenteditable/) следует, что `contentEditable` работает **почти** для всех HTML элементов, хотя в данной ситуации canvas [хорошо работает](http://jsfiddle.net/ssgyyuo6/) внутри contentEditable.

Стоит смотреть логи в момент, когда "не работает",  и вероятнее всего он не работает, потому, что к нему не привязаны никакие обработчики событий

Comment: Canvas в contentEditable, если прописывать сразу в html, работает. А вот как его туда вставить уже после загрузки?

Comment: в чем заключается такая надобность? Пользователь сам может вставлять сколько хочет canvas'ов и рисовать в них?

Comment: Да именно так. Идея в том чтобы не использовать дополнительные страницы и прочие отображения.

Comment: И как определяется, что canvas отвечает действиям пользователя? В примере выше никаких обработчиков событий не замечено